# I have to remove gradient effect from my colors array in ios

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, gradient

```
- (void) initColorsSet {
colors = [NSMutableArray new];

[colors addObject:[UIColor colorWithR:51  G:102 B:255]]; 
[colors addObject:[UIColor colorWithR:137 G:173 B:1]]; 
[colors addObject:[UIColor colorWithR:253 G:213 B:55]]; 
[colors addObject:[UIColor colorWithR:239 G:78  B:34]];
[colors addObject:[UIColor colorWithR:186 G:0  B:187]];
[colors addObject:[UIColor colorWithR:255 G:109  B:254]];
[colors addObject:[UIColor colorWithR:0 G:193  B:0]];
[colors addObject:[UIColor colorWithR:101 G:255 B:255]]; 
[colors addObject:[UIColor colorWithR:233 G:0  B:104]];
[colors addObject:[UIColor colorWithR:196 G:255  B:104]];
[colors addObject:[UIColor colorWithR:254 G:240  B:170]];
[colors addObject:[UIColor colorWithR:2 G:227  B:166]];

for (NSInteger i = [colors count]; i < 60; i++ ) {
    [colors addObject:[UIColor colorWithR:(((float)arc4random()/0x100000000)*255)
                                        G:(((float)arc4random()/0x100000000)*255)
                                        B:(((float)arc4random()/0x100000000)*255) ]]; 
}
```

}

```
- (UIColor*) colorByIndex:(int)index {
    int trueIndex = index >= 12 ? index % 12 : index;
    return [colors objectAtIndex:trueIndex];
}
```

from above code i need to remove gradient effect , How could I do this?
Thanks

Comment: serisouly ??? one doen not simply produce gradient effect by adding color objects to an NSMutable array. There's a whole bunch of other stuffs.

Comment: try to add alpha to UIcolor like this..[UIColor colorWithRed:32.0/255.0 green:32.0/255.0 blue:32.0/255.0 alpha:0.0]; i dont know weather i works or not.

Comment: I have edit my answer....We are using above method to show the colors

Comment: Presumably whatever gradient you add is done in `colorWithR:G:B:`?

Comment: Your code doesn't even produce gradient effect, it just add colors to an array !

Comment: Where are you using these colors ?, maybe it's overlapping with a transparent image and it's only appearing to have a gradient.